# Poo Problema ayuda declaracion variable clases

Tags: java, array, netbeans, poo, eclipse

Buenos dias quiero una ayuda pues tengo un problema al realizar el codigo, el problema es que quiero pedir los datos y dejarlos guardados en una clase pero nose como hacerlo:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63Uhd3pUZxA&list=PLU8oAlHdN5BktAXdEVCLUYzvDyqRQJ2lk&index=35
Este es el ejercicio ahi se establecen los datos pero yo quiero es pedirlo (Y guardalos en un metodo estatico) Si alguien es tan amable me puede AYUDAR GRACIAS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va como texto, además no hay necesidad de escribir en inglés pues estamos en so en español

Comment: no veo setters, ese puede ser el problema.

Comment: El problema es que `Empleado[i]` es de tipo `empleado` y estás intentando asignarle otros tipos de datos (`String`, `int`, `double`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te has hecho un lío con las mayúsculas de Empleado.

Una clase u objeto (en Java es lo mismo) va siempre en UpperCamelCase, en tu caso tienes la clase Empleado, lo cual es correcto.

Pero presta atención a las mayúsculas, lo que quieres es crear un array de Empleado no de empleado, no es lo mismo.

```
empleado [] Empleado = new empleado[1]; // <-- Esto está al revés, es incorrecto
Empleado[] empleado = new Empleado[1]; // <-- Esta es la forma correcta

// Fíjate en que la clase está marcada de otro color.
```

En la segunda línea lo que dice es lo siguiente:
-Quiero un array cuyo contenedor sea tipo Empleado, que el nombre de la variable sea empleado y que contenga objetos de la clase Empleado, con un espacio de almacenamiento en total de 1.

En contestación a tu pregunta, lo que quieres hacer es crear una instancia de objeto de tipo Empleado y posteriormente almacenarlo en el array de tipo Empleado.

Así es como crearías un objeto de tipo Empleado y como lo almacenarías en el array:

```
Empleado nuevoEmpleado = new Empleado("Jose", 200.00, 2018, 10, 20);
empleado[0] = nuevoEmpleado;
```

Date cuenta que primero que nada antes de crear el empleado necesitamos el valor de sus atributos, es decir el nombre, el sueldo, etc. Para posteriormente crear la nueva instancia y luego almacenarlo en el array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < empleado.length; i++) {

   // Fíjate en como primero se han de substraer los datos del empleado

   System.out.println("Introduce el nombre");
   String nombre = datos.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Introduce el sueldo");
   double saldo = datos.nextDouble();
   System.out.println("Introduce el año de alta");
   int anyo = datos.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Introduce el mes de alta");
   int mes = datos.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Introduce el día de alta");
   int dia = datos.nextInt();

   // Ya tenemos los datos necesarios para instanciar un nuevo empleado

   Empleado nuevoEmpleado = new Empleado(nombre, sueldo, anyo, mes, dia);

   // Ahora solo queda guardarlo en el array

   empleado[i] = nuevoEmpleado;

}
```

Corrige las mayúsculas, recuerda que las clases van en UpperCamelCase y el nombre de las variables en lowerCamelCase.